# Viewing microsoft office files programaticly on linux

Tags: linux, printing, ms-office

I want to code a desktop program to print microsoft office files (doc, docx, xls and xlxs) on linux machine. But I don't know how to print them without corruption on output.

Is there a way to print or convert to an other format the file as %100 same of the view on microsoft office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libreoffice API might be a good place to start, particularly the examples:
http://api.libreoffice.org/

I haven't used the API myself but have used open/libre-office as an alternative to word for quite a while.

However, you say '100%' the same as in office? I wouldn't be confident of that. Depending on the document it's likely to be fine, but there are some things which don't seem to convert well.  If you're working on linux, you're not likely to have the same fonts installed as whichever windows/mac machine made the document.

If the documents you're processing are all of the same/similar layout/template, and you're able to test a few first, it should be fine. But if you're processing any sort of word document, some may not convert completely without a bit of human input. Depends how much difference you can tolerate. If you want completely consistent printing across platforms, I guess that's what pdfs are for.